# read.csv is skipping lines with a leading whitespace in R

Tags: r, csv, read.table

I have csv files in which a couple of the fields in the first column have a leading whitespace.  `read.csv` considers the whole line blank, even though there are data in the line.  I can use `blank.lines.skip = FALSE`, but it just reads it in as a blank line.

I'd like to read in the data on those lines, so how do I get `read.csv` (or `read.table` or something) to ignore that whitespace?

The data look like this:

```
Sample Name Air BaseMixture

Offset  -0.0338367  -0.0338367

Slope   0.0200808   0.0200808

LiveTime    180.236 180.252

RealTime    255.934 280.701

LTMultiplier    1   1

.
.
.
```

Offset and Slope seem to have some sort of whitespace that makes `read.csv` give me this:

```
    Sample.Name Air BaseMixture

1   NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA
3   LiveTime    180.236 180.252
4   RealTime    255.934 280.701 
5   LTMultiplier    1   1
```

Your help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What command do you use to read your file ? The default for read.table is sep"", which is one or more white space. So read.table(file="yourfile.csv") should work.

Comment: Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Asking your question(s) in a good way will makes everybody's life easier and will ensure you to get a quick and informative answer.

Comment: Please consider clarifying your use of the term csv. A csv will have actual _commas_ in the file. Your example does not, so it makes absolutely no sense to use `read.csv` rather than `read.table`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
read.csv('filename.csv', strip.white=TRUE)
```